# Viewing the last edit date of a procedure in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Server Management Studio, there's a tab called Object Explorer Details that you can look at to see when a table or a procedure is created or last modified.

Is there something similar for Oracle SQL Developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View > Reports > Data Dictionary Reports

Open the All Objects Report

[image]

You can filter/sort the report to restrict to a specific schema or object type, or even filter on the last updated date (Last_DDL)

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

*** Query way ***

With Oracle, you can query the view `all_objects`

*** GUI way ***

Search for the objects that you want and the check the Details tab

Let say you want information about OE_ACKNOWLEDGMENT_PUB package body

[image: Searching for OE_ACKNOWLEDGMENT_PUB package]

Then you click on the object name

[image: object name]

Then you click on Details tab

[image: Details tab]

Comment: This works, but is there any other way you know of where I don't have to click on each object individually?  I was hoping for one page like in SQL Server where it gives you that info for every object in a collection (i.e. all tables, all views, etc...).

Comment: @JohnnyBones I edited my answer, use `all_objects` view